# C# LINQ compound from vs. subquery

Tags: c#, linq, subquery

in LINQ (query syntax) I can have multiple froms.

As far as I can read:

"a query expression can contain sub-queries, which also begin with a from clause..."

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/from-clause

But whats the difference between an compound from (which uses multiple froms) and a subquery? An example for an compound from is something like this:

```
List<A> persons = new List<A>();

var query = from mychild in persons
            from ch in mychild.Children 
            from c in ch.Children 
            select c;
```

Or ist the second line "from ch in .." a subquery for the first line (from mychild) and in the third line "from c" a subquery for from ch? And compound from is the name for all off the subqueries?

Answer (score 2):

Every query syntax query must end in a `select` expression.  This is how you can differentiate a subquery.  If you were to interpret:

```
from c in ch.Children 
select c;
```

As a subquery, then the query would be:

```
var query = from mychild in persons
            from ch in mychild.Children 
            (from c in ch.Children 
            select c);
```

And the outer query:

```
from mychild in persons
from ch in mychild.Children
```

would have no `select` expression.

Additionally, if this were a subquery, it would just be sticking a query to the end of a `from` statement and not describing how it's used.  For it to be included in the outer query it'd need to be *used* somehow.  To have the query of `Children` be a subquery you could do something like this:

```
var query = from mychild in persons
            from ch in mychild.Children 
            from outerChild in 
                (from innerChild in ch.Children 
                select innerChild)
            select outerChild;
```

Obviously this isn't a useful way to have a subquery, but that's the type of transformation it would take to have it interpreted as a subquery.

So yeah, just count the number of `select` keywords to see the number of queries.

Answer (score 1):

This construction translates to `.SelectMany`.  It can be used to navigate down a 1-many relationship.

```
var query =
  from customer in customers
  from order in customer.Orders
  select order;
```

---

This construction generates a subquery.

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Today;
var query =
  from customer in customers
  let orderCount = (
    from order in customer.Orders
    where order.ShipDate == today
    select order).Count()
  select new {customer, orderCount};
```

Answer (score 0):

A compound from clause is when you access an inner element from the outer query. Otherwise, you can define a sub-query that operates on a different data source.

Consider the following example:

```
var somePersons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Names = new List<string> { "John", "Smith" } },
    new Person { Names = new List<string> { "Mike", "Soandso" } }
};

var otherPersons = new List<Person>
{
    new Person { Names = new List<string> { "Jane", "Doe" } },
    new Person { Names = new List<string> { "Sarah", "Connor" } }
};

var query = from person1 in somePersons
            from name1 in person1.Names
            from person2 in otherPersons
            from name2 in person2.Names
            select new Person { Names = new List<string> { name1, name2 } };
```